# Search query shows all results when clicking search button

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

I got a simple search query that works, but shows all results when the search button is clicked without a search input.

It also shows results with parent_id 26 or cattid 26 which I want to prevent in my query. Why is it still showing results with those id's and how can I prevent every result appearing on the result page when there is no search input?

How it is build:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <div class="mn-wrap">
        <form method="post" class="form" action="zoeken/">
            <div class="search-wrap">
                <button class="search-button animate" type="submit" title="Start zoeken">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                <input type="text" name="zoekterm" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Zoek...">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule         ^zoeken/ /zoeken.php?zoeken=1 [L]
```

Queries:

```
if ($_GET['zoeken'] != '') {

    $zoekterm = $_POST['zoekterm'];

    // zoeken
    $zoeken    = "SELECT * FROM `lb_content` WHERE catid NOT IN ('1', '26', '27', '28') and  introtext LIKE '%".$conn->real_escape_string($zoekterm)."%' OR title LIKE '%".$conn->real_escape_string($zoekterm)."%'";
    $zoekencon = $conn->query($zoeken);
    $zoekeni   = array();
    while ($zoekeni[] = $zoekencon->fetch_array());

    // zoeken c
    $zoekc    = "SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id NOT IN ('1', '26', '27', '28') and level = 2 and description LIKE '%".$conn->real_escape_string($zoekterm)."%' OR title LIKE '%".$conn->real_escape_string($zoekterm)."%'";
    $zoekccon = $conn->query($zoekc);
    $zoekci   = array();
    while ($zoekci[] = $zoekccon->fetch_array());
}
```

And finally the result page:

```
<div class="row multi-columns-row alt-features-grid">

    <?

    $aantal = count($zoekeni) + count($zoekci) - 2;

    if($aantal == 0){

        echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="alt-features-item align-center">
                        <div class="alt-features-icon">
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="alt-features-title font-alt">Er zijn geen resultaten</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    }

    if($zoekeni[0]['id']){
        foreach ($zoekeni as $resultaat) {

            if($resultaat['introtext']){

                echo '

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="alt-features-item align-center">
                            <div class="alt-features-icon">
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="alt-features-title font-alt">'.$resultaat['title'].'</h3>
                            <div class="alt-features-descr align-left">
                                '.IntroText($resultaat['introtext']).'<br><br>
                                 <div class="align-right">
                                    <a href="'.$resultaat['alias'].'.html" style="text-decoration:none">Lees meer</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                ';

            }

        }
    }


    if($zoekci[0]['id']){
        foreach ($zoekci as $resultaat) {

            if($resultaat['description']){

                echo '

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="alt-features-item align-center">
                            <div class="alt-features-icon">
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="alt-features-title font-alt">'.$resultaat['title'].'</h3>
                            <div class="alt-features-descr align-left">
                                   '.IntroText($resultaat['description']).'<br><br>
                                 <div class="align-right">
                                    <a href="'.$resultaat['alias'].'.html" style="text-decoration:none">Lees meer</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                ';

            }

        }
    }

    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Note that you have: `if ($_GET['zoeken'] != '') {`instead of `if($_POST...)` to avoid searching empty value.

Comment: search only when there is some words in "zoekterm"... if zoekterm is empty, query will search where `introtext LIKE '%%'` which would match all.

Comment: I added an if statement so that part is fixed, but it still shows results with for example catid 26 or 27 while I state in the queries that results with that catid or parent_id should not be read.

Comment: This is a different question from the original one and should be asked in its own topic.